# Getting a different random each time python

Tags: python

so the program runs well. The issue is, if I want to play again, it calls the same random numbers each time. How do I make it so I calls a different random number and card each time I want to play again? Thanks.

```
import random
import math
import time
import sys

Hearts = "Hearts"
Clubs = "Clubs"
Diamonds = "Diamonds"
Spades = "Spades"

number1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
number1 = random.choice(number1)
number2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
number2 = random.choice(number2)
number3 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
number3 = random.choice(number3)

card1 = [Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
card1 = random.choice(card1)
card2 = [Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
card2 = random.choice(card2)
card3 = [Hearts, Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
card3 = random.choice(card3)

blacklist = ["King" "Queen", "Jack"]
blacklist = random.choice(blacklist)

ace = ["Ace"]
ace = random.choice(ace)

runningtotal = number1 + number2
roundtotal = runningtotal + number3

def startup():
    print("Starting game... Your first cards are being drawn")
    round1()

def round1():
    if number1 == 10:
        print ("{} of {}".format(blacklist, card1))
        round2()
    elif number1 == 1:
        print("{} of {}".format(ace, card1))
        round2()
    else:
        print ("{} of {}".format(number1, card1))
        round2()

def round2():
    if number2 == 10:
        print ("{} of {}".format(blacklist, card2))
        round3()
    elif number2 == 1:
        print("{} of {}".format(ace, card2))
        round3()
    else:
        print ("{} of {}".format(number2, card2))
        round3()

def round3():
    startr3 = input("Would you like to be dealt another card? Your total is... {}".format(runningtotal))
    if startr3 == "yes":
        if number3 == 10:
            print("{} of {}".format(blacklist, card3))
        elif number3 == 1:
            print("{} of {}".format(ace, card3))
        else:
            print("{} of {}".format(number3, card3))
            if roundtotal >= 22:
                loose()
            else:
                print("You win!")
                again = input("Do you want to play again?")
                if again == "yes":
                    round1()
                elif again == "no":
                    endgame()

def endgame():
    print("Thankyou for playing")

def loose():
    looseg = input("Your total was above 21! Do you want to play again?")
    if looseg == "yes":
        number1()
    elif looseg == "no":
        endgame()
startup()
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the real problem here is that you only choose your numbers once, when the program starts up. Instead, you need to pick them each time they're needed. 
like this:

```
def round1():
    number1 = random.randint(1, 10)
    if number1 == 10:
        print ("{} of {}".format(blacklist, card1))
        round2()
    elif number1 == 1:
        print("{} of {}".format(ace, card1))
        round2()
    else:
        print ("{} of {}".format(number1, card1))
        round2()
```

Comment: How would I go about getting a running total then? (Im very new to python :P)

Comment: You could pass relevant values to the functions that you're calling, and keep the state that way, or you could set up a global variable and update that as you go.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `random.seed()` method once at the start of your code should solve the problem.

Comment: Great answer - if you're writing C. python's `random` is a well-behaved module, it knows to seed itself. `random.seed()` is mostly useful for setting up a specific starting state for the random generator - that is, for getting the same pseudorandom sequence each time, ie, for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the generator using random.seed(), which will use the system time as a seed.

Currently your program is using the same seed each time you run it.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way would be to call a "setup" function before calling `round1()` in this part of the code (the part where the player loses too):

```
# ...
if again == "yes":
    # here
    round1()
elif again == "no":
#...
```

This function would need to change the values of the global variables you define in the beginning. That way, you would have a different hand.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use :

```
from random import randint
number1 = randint(0,10)
```

Instead of putting a whole list ?